# Optimal Stopping Theorem for UI Martingales

Tags: probability, martingales, uniform-integrability

In my notes, I was given that:

"Let $X_n$ be an $F_n$ (super,sub) martingale and $\tau$ an $F_n$ stopping time. Then $X_{n \wedge \tau}$ is a (super, sub) martingale wrt $F_n$ and $F_{n \wedge \tau}$"

However in the section about Uniformly Integrable Martingales it says:

"Let $X_n$ be a UI Martingale. Then for any $F_n$ stopping time $\tau$, $X_{n \wedge \tau}$ is Uniformly integrable."

Is it not true that if $X_n$ is a UI Martingale then $X_{n \wedge \tau}$ is a Uniformly integrable martingale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{X_n\}$ is UI then $X_n=E(X|\mathcal F_n)$ for some integrable $X$ and $X_{n\wedge \tau }=E(X|\mathcal F_{n\wedge \tau })$ which makes $\{X_{n\wedge \tau\} }\}$ also UI.

Comment: I understand that. But Is $X_{n \wedge \tau}$ a UI **martingale**

Comment: @AnonymousEmu A stopped martingale is a martingale.

Comment: @AnonymousEmu For any increasing sequence $\mathcal G_n$ of sigma fields and any integrable random variable $X$, $\{EX| \mathcal G_n)\}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale.

Comment: sorry to be persistent, but is this still true even if $\tau$ is not a finite stopping time?

Comment: @AnonymousEmu Yes, it is true even if $\tau $ is not almost surely finite.